# How to call a function to execute on the url

Tags: php

I wrote a code which is working fine but now I want it to be in a function so as to call it on the url. I will really appreciate if you guys can help.

Here is my code.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Unable to connect".mysqli_connect_error();
}

function day(){
$sql = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(user_registerdate, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM ts_user 
        WHERE DATE(user_registerdate) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY";
    if($result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo $row['user_uname']."<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

And am calling it on the url as 
http://localhost/test/index.php/day

Please telling me what am doing wrong. am I calling it wrongly on the url?

Comment: Where is controller nane?

Comment: am not using a framework, i just wanted to know if it can be done using just php.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run before you can walk; this sort of *hints* at URL Rewriting with a front controller (probably an MVC pattern) calling something like a `dayAction()` method - you see it with things like Phalcon or Magento. So yes it's possible but not the way you're attempting it - and it's not really *"entry level"* PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to break the url to get the last parameter after the `index.php`, in your case it is `day`. On the behalf of this parameter make different code blocks and execute them as per the parameter passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call function like this in core php

You have to call like this:

**First Way:**
`http://localhost/test/index.php`

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testing");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Unable to connect".mysqli_connect_error();
    } else {
        day($conn);
    }
```

**Second Way:**
`http://localhost/test/index.php?day=yes`

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testing");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Unable to connect".mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
echo "connection successfull";
}

if($_GET['day']) {
    day($conn);
}
```

**Declare function :**

```
function day($conn){
}
```

====================================

## Directly call function from url

**test.php**

```
class Test
{
    const DB_SERVER = "localhost";
    const DB_USER = "root";
    const DB_PASSWORD = "";
    const DB = "testing";

    public function processApi(){
        $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/","",$_REQUEST['func'])));
        if((int)method_exists($this,$func) > 0)
            $this->$func();
        else
            echo "Method not exist";
    }

    private function get_data() {
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testing");
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Unable to connect".mysqli_connect_error();
        } else {
            //replace your query here
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee";
            if($result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo $row['name']."<br />";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$test = new Test;
$test->processApi();

 ?>
```

Define routing in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php?func=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

You can run this example like :
`http://localhost/core_route/get_data`

[For more help visit this](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Comment: i don't think i need a get variable, all i wanted is to call the function directly from the url. thanks for answering anyways.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like that:

```
call_user_func($_GET['function']);
```

And use URL `http://localhost/test/index.php?function=day`
In this way you can execute any function that you pass by GET parameter.

Answer (score -2):

You have to tell PHP, that you are using `$conn` from another scope.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Simply use `global $conn` inside function tags.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Unable to connect".mysqli_connect_error();
}
function day(){
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(user_registerdate, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM ts_user 
        WHERE DATE(user_registerdate) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY";
    if($result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo $row['user_uname']."<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried something like that but it's still not fetching the data. Thanks for your response.